# Highcharts in Bootstrap tabs: non-visible chart breaks on window resize?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I have two Highcharts charts in separate Bootstrap tabs. They initially render perfectly, but when I resize the window, the non-visible chart breaks.

Here is a demo of the problem - to see the bug, please resize the window and then clicking on the non-visible tab: http://jsfiddle.net/0hw3zk5t/6/

Here's my HTML (just because SO wants me to include some code, but you probably don't want hundreds of lines of Highcharts config options):

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" id="summary-tab" class="summary-tab active">
    <a href="#summary-panel" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Show summary</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" id="chart-tab" class="chart-tab">
    <a href="#chart-panel" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Show over time</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="summary-panel" class="summary-tab">
      <div class="chart-container">
      <div id="summarychart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="chart-panel" class="chart-tab">
        <div class="chart-container">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It could works: Change width:100% !important; to width:auto !important; and  width: 100%; to  width: auto; (highcharts-container and #chart, #summarychart)

Comment: Thanks - tried updating as you suggest. It fixes the resize bug, but now the second chart is falling off the edge of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/0hw3zk5t/7/

Comment: Check my answer below, I think it fix everything

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes basically  from the boostrap `display:none` estate used to hide tab content. The chart lose the width when it's inicialized . So what the following css does, is to avoid display:none and let to the content to be adjusted automatically.

```
#tabs {
  width: 100%;
}
#tabs li {
  width: 25%;
}
.tab-pane {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tab-pane.active {

  background: white;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.tab-pane .chart-title-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.highcharts-container {
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
}
.chart-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}
#chart, #summarychart {
    width: 100%;

}
.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
    height: auto;      
} 
.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
    display: block;     
    height: 0;         
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}
```